# How to label a multidimensional scaling plot when names are in struct

Tags: arrays, matlab, plot

I made a multidimensional scaling plot with Matlab's mdscale function. According to the instructions
 [here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/stats/multidimensional-scaling.html), the points can be labelled with the gname function. However, the dummy data they use in the tutorial is structured in cells as far as I can see and I am using a struct array.

I have a 1x14 struct array with 2 fields: speaker and name, which I built like this:

```
speaker(1).data = importdata([path,'file1']);
speaker(1).name = 'speaker 1';
speaker(2).data = importdata([path,'file2']);
speaker(2).name = 'speaker 2';
```

Then I calculated a distance matrix "d" from speaker(i).data and performed multidimensional scaling:

```
[Y,stress] = mdscale(d,6,'criterion','metricstress');
plot(Y(:,1),Y(:,2),'o','LineWidth',2);
xlabel('Distance')
ylabel('Distance')
gname(speaker().name(distances))
```

The last line "gname..." is wrong, it gives me the error "Field reference for multiple structure elements that is followed by more reference blocks is an error."
I don't know how I can get the names displayed on my plot when I have a struct instead of a cell. Can somebody help please?

Edit:

I managed to convert speaker().name into a cell array "names" and call

```
gname(names)
```

It is working now! Thanks for the helpful comment.

Comment: Did you try passing the names from your struct to a cell array?

Comment: If that solved the problem, just post your solution as an answer and accept it. So that others who may have the same problem find the solution and that your question has an accepted answer (easier to spot).